# e2e Protractor test run locally but not on bamboo

Tags: angular, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, e2e-testing, bamboo

I run the e2e tests locally in my shell with npm run e2e and they all pass.
But on bamboo this doesn´t work.
My protractor.conf.js:

```
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

/**
 * @type { import("protractor").Config }
 */
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  suites: {
    regression: ['./src/**/*.e2e-KFZwithGivenTypeAndCompany.ts','./src/**/*.e2e-KFZwithoutGivenTypeAndCompany.ts','./src/**/*.e2e-upload.ts','./src/**/*.e2e-error_messages.ts'],  //Name der Datei entsprechen app.e2e-spec.ts
    functionality: ['./src/**/*.e2e-upload.ts','./src/**/*.e2e-error_messages.ts'],
    KFZ: ['./src/**/*.e2e-KFZwithGivenTypeAndCompany.ts','./src/**/*.e2e-KFZwithoutGivenTypeAndCompany.ts'],
    HRV: ['./src/**/*.e2e-HRV.ts'],
    PHV: ['./src/**/*.e2e-PHV.ts'],
    Error: ['./src/**/*.e2e-error_messages.ts']
  },
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome' ,
    
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ["--headless","--no-sandbox", "--window-size=800,600", "--disable-dev-shm-usage","--disable-setuid-sandbox","--remote-debugging-port=9222","--disable-extensions","--disable-gpu","disable-infobars",'--disable-web-security','--allow-running-insecure-content']
  }
  },
 
  directConnect: true,
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 90000,
    isVerbose: true,
    includeStackTrace:true,
    print: function() {}
  },

  onPrepare: function() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: require('path').join(__dirname, './tsconfig.json')
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: {displayStacktrace: 'pretty'}}));

  }
```

My Job has three npm task:
install webdriver-manager
update webdriver-manager
run e2e

package.json:
"e2e": "ng e2e --port 4201"

my application is compiled properly but the tests doesn´t starts:
build   28-Oct-2021 10:47:41    ✔ Compiled successfully.
build   28-Oct-2021 10:47:42    [10:47:42] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
build   28-Oct-2021 10:47:42    [10:47:42] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
build   28-Oct-2021 10:47:43    [10:47:43] E/launcher - unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
build   28-Oct-2021 10:47:43      (chrome not reachable)
build   28-Oct-2021 10:47:43      (The process started from chrome location /snap/bin/chromium is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
build   28-Oct-2021 10:47:43      (Driver info: chromedriver=95.0.4638.54 (d31a821ec901f68d0d34ccdbaea45b4c86ce543e-refs/branch-heads/4638@{#871}),platform=Linux 5.10.0-1044-oem x86_64)

Does anyone can help?